# Rspec: API controller specs running with zero failures on local/server CLI but fails some tests in Jenkins CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jenkins, rspec, jruby

I have a jenkins CI setup configured to run specs on each git push. When I run these specs with "rspec" on my local it works fine with zero failures, also I ran specs on the CLI of jenkins agent the specs ran with zero failures. But when the same specs run in jenkins CI, some cases fail.

I have been trying to figure out the issue but have not found the real reason for this behavior yet.

Can anyone please help with this issue?

Comment: Can you post your failed spec file? Seems to be a Jenkins config issue

Comment: We need to know at a minimum what kind of spec, what error you see, and possibly what kind of gems you have configured for running your test suite. Configuration of database cleaner coupled with feature tests are one common cause of intermittent failing tests.

Comment: By default, rspec runs tests in a specific order. But, Jenkins environments are often configured to run the tests in a random order. This can lead to situations like the one you described. Check your Jenkins configuration to see if it calls rspec with the `--order` option. If so, try running your specs locally with the same option. Or, just try running the tests with `rspec --order rand`.